# Make Chinese text bold in plot title

Tags: r, plot, multilingual

I am working on multilingual plots where I  need to plot Chinese text in R plot which is bold. But when I use font.main=4, still Chinese text is not bold.

```
pdf(paste("./tmp/population.pdf",sep=""), width=10 , height =11,  family="GB1")
plot(x,main="中国的",cex.axis= 1, cex.lab=1.2,font.main=4)
dev.off()
```

[image]

How can I fix this problem

Comment: What does `names( pdfFonts())` return. If it has a bold version and you look at it with whatever viewer is appropriate to you unstated operating system, does it look bold?

Comment: It has following versions: [1] "serif"                "sans"                 "mono"                
 [4] "AvantGarde"           "Bookman"              "Courier"             
 [7] "Helvetica"            "Helvetica-Narrow"     "NewCenturySchoolbook"
[10] "Palatino" "Times" "URWGothic"           
[13] "URWBookman"  "NimbusMon" "NimbusSan"           
[16] "URWHelvetica" "NimbusSanCond" "CenturySch"          
[19] "URWPalladio" "NimbusRom" "URWTimes"            
[22] "Japan1"  "Japan1HeiMin" "Japan1GothicBBB"     
[25] "Japan1Ryumin"  "Korea1" "Korea1deb"           
[28] "CNS1"  "GB1"

Comment: It has GB1 but not bold, Pls help me.

Comment: There are recommendations on websites to consider the Hei font. It does not have a bold set but appears more bold than the GB font. Also this appears in the help( Type1Font ) page: "There are no real bold or italic versions of CID fonts (bold/italic were very rarely used in traditional CJK topography), and for the pdf device all four font faces will be identical. However, for the postscript device, bold and italic (and bold italic) are emulated."

Comment: I got error message while using Hei instead of GB1 Error in pdf(x, width = 6.6, height = 4.2, pointsize = 28, family = "Hei") : 
  unknown family 'Hei' Any example will help me a lot

Comment: I m using following command grid.text(title, x=0.33, y=1, just=c("left", "top"),gp=gpar(fontsize=18, fontfamily="Hei",fontface ="bold")) still getting same error.

Comment: I do not see any code that would map the Hei font to the name "Hei". You need to name the file where the postscript or pdffont is located. See ?pdfFonts for example. That gives an example using a file named "Adobe-Japan1-UniJIS-UCS2-H.afm".

Comment: I found GB1 (PDF) ‘STSong-Light-Acro’ when i used ?pdfFonts. How can i change it Hei. Pls help me out of this pblm. Thanks

Comment: Change ... what? Found ... how?, where? Am I suppose to do some sort of search? And ... Why should I? Why are you not adding details to the question by editing it?

Answer (score 0):

As @DWin suggested in the comments, the Hei font family is "bolder" than GB1 and therefore might do the trick.
It is not default in R so you have to map the Hei font to the name "Hei" to use it in `pdf` or you have to use `cairo_pdf`.

With `cairo_pdf` it is straightforward, you can literally use any font library installed on your computer:

```
cairo_pdf("population.pdf", width=10 , height=11,  family="Hei")
```

[image]

Otherwise to map the Hei font, you need to locate on your computer the font library in format `afm` (let's say for the sake of the exercise that it s `~/Library/Fonts//Hei.afm`).

```
hei <- Type1Font("Hei", c("~/Library/Fonts//Hei.afm", "", "", "")) 
# the three empty spaces would have been the place for respectively the bold, the italic and the bold italic font libraries
pdfFonts(A=hei)
pdf("population.pdf", width=10 , height=11,  family="A")
```

Comment: Thanks, i just checked. I could not find Hei.afm file. Where is this file? Do i need to install on my pc(ubuntu). Same with cairo_pdf (Actually cairoPDF) but output does not show chinese characters.

Comment: If you want to use this method, yes you need to install it (and i have no idea where to find it for free). I personnally don't have that file: I have `Hei.ttf` and that's why I use the `cairo_pdf` method. And it is `cairo_pdf` from the `grDevices` package (one of the base packages installed by default in R) and not `cairoPDF` from the `Cairo` package I'm talking about. In `cairo_pdf` you have to name the font family as it is named on your system font list. On a Mac, the Hei font family is simply called "Hei" hence the call I wrote. On Windows, it is called "MSHei" I believe.